# Envoy filter in istio unable to apply rate limit based on regex

Tags: istio, rate-limiting, envoyproxy

I am working on rate limit using the istio. I want to apply different rate limit based on the regex. The url which has /api/iam/.* should have rate limit of 2 req/minute and default rate limit on other paths should be 100 req/s. I am trying to use

```
rate_limits:
              - actions:
                 - header_value_match:
                    descriptor_value: two_legged_path
                    headers:
                    - name: ":path"
                      string_match:
                        safe_regex:
                          google_re2: {}
                          regex: "api/iam/.*"
```

we used string_match with safe_regex but it is not working. It always applies the default behaviour which is 100 req/s. Could you please help I have followed numerious examples and nothing seemed to work.

The full configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-local-ratelimit-svc
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: iam-authn-service
      env: az-dev
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
            type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
            value:
              stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "inbound|http|8080"
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          route:
            rate_limits:
              - actions:
                 - header_value_match:
                    descriptor_value: two_legged_path
                    headers:
                    - name: ":path"
                      string_match:
                        safe_regex:
                          google_re2: {}
                          regex: "api/iam/.*"
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
              type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
              value:
                stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter
                descriptors:
                - entries:
                  - key: header_match
                    value: two_legged_path
                  token_bucket:
                    max_tokens: 2
                    tokens_per_fill: 2
                    fill_interval: 60s
                token_bucket:
                  max_tokens: 100
                  tokens_per_fill: 100
                  fill_interval: 1s
                filter_enabled:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enabled
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                filter_enforced:
                  runtime_key: local_rate_limit_enforced
                  default_value:
                    numerator: 100
                    denominator: HUNDRED
                response_headers_to_add:
                  - append: false
                    header:
                      key: x-local-rate-limit
                      value: 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

The istio doesn't use the latest envoy, the valid doc: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.1/api-v3/type/matcher/v3/regex.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-type-matcher-v3-regexmatcher-googlere2

use safe_regex_match instead of string_match